# App runner 404 when using explicit 443 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-app-runner

I am running a custom container in App Runner. The app is running fine with the default url provided by App Runner. The problem is that when I use the explicit port 443 I get an 404 error.

`https://xxx.us-east-1.awsapprunner.com` -> This works fine

`https://xxx.us-east-1.awsapprunner.com:443` -> 404 Not Found

What is going on here?